# Display current user data on front-end - Gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have created a Gutenberg block for display current user data but its display only admin data because when I save post that's time current user is admin so its display only admin data for all user but I want current user detail.

I have try this code.

```
let current_user = wp.data.select("core").getCurrentUser();
console.log("current_user", current_user.id);
```

Please let me know how can I display current user meta fields in Gutenberg block.
Thanks in advance.

**Note : Serverside render is not used in my case because I want rich editor for this block.**

Answer (score 2):

Using `wp.data.select("core").getCurrentUser()`, you can only retrieve the current editing user on Gutenberg Block Editor, when you save the information, the data of the editing user is saved as static data. So you will always get the same data on the front-end.

You have to use  [dynamic blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) for your requirements.

On JS use the **edit** function only.

For the **save** function use PHP.

You can view [Post Title Block from the core Gutenberg Block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-title) for a modern example.